# .nextUntil Not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have below scenario where .nextUntil not Working in jquery.
Where i have a simple table with class name on tr and want to find next class element using jquery.

**HTML :**

```
 <table class="table">
       <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="text" class="location" style="width: 95%" /></td>
              </tr>
               <tr class="locationtoggle">
               <td class="tdColor">X:
                 <input type="text" class="X" style="width: 40%" /><br />
                 Y :
                <input type="text" class="Y" style="width: 40%" /><br />
                 </td>
                  </tr>
                   </table>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
 $(".location").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            var split = $(this).val().split(',');
            if (split.length > 1) {
                $(this).nextUntil("X").val(split[0]);
                $(this).nextUntil("Y").val(split[1]);
            }
            else
                alert("Please Check Values.");
        }
        else
            alert("Please Check Values.");
    }
});
```

Can anybody help me out for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to traverse to closest parent tr, traverse to next tr using `.next()` and then find the input elements in it :

```
 $(this).closest('tr').next().find(".X").val(split[0]);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5m9o5yfn/)**